# Sails.js Asset delivery to http

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am new to sails and node and I have a question about how I deliver models through a controller on the webpage with ejs tags <%-%> or <%=%>.
So, I have 2 models with their controllers Model1, Model2 and Model1Controller, Model2Controller.
I want to show the Model1 attribute (let's say name Model1.name) in the Model2Controller show/findall action.

Comment: when you says model 2 controller, does that mean your using blueprints and attempting to to populate model2 with model1?

Answer (score 1):

Models are global in sails, i.e., you can access `Model1` in your `Model2Controller`. for e.g.

```
someMethodInModel2Controller: function(req, res) {
    Model1.find({}, function(err, foundRecords){
        // Do whatever you want to do with the records from Model1
   }
}
```